# jquery code working with version 1.7.1 but not with latest version

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, updates

i'm using a jquery code on my website to control a slideshow.
i've collected some codes supposed to work with jquery version 1.7.1.
it works perfectly, but when using jquery latest version my code doesn't work.
is there a lot of difference between those 2 versions ?
is there a way of fixing it because I would like to use jquery latest version.

here is my js code :

```
function slideshow(){

var $descriptions = $('#carousel-descriptions').children('li'),
    $controls = $('#carousel-controls').find('span'),
    $carousel = $('#carousel')
        .roundabout({childSelector:"li", minOpacity:0, maxOpacity:1, minScale: 1, btnNext: ".next", btnPrev:".prev",})
        .on('focus', 'li', function() {
            var slideNum = $carousel.roundabout("getChildInFocus");

            $descriptions.add($controls).removeClass('current');
            $($descriptions.get(slideNum)).addClass('current');
            $($controls.get(slideNum)).addClass('current');
        });

$controls.on('click dblclick', function() {
    var slideNum = -1,
        i = 0, len = $controls.length;

    for (; i<len; i++) {
        if (this === $controls.get(i)) {
            slideNum = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (slideNum >= 0) {
        $controls.removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $carousel.roundabout('animateToChild', slideNum);
    }
});

}
```

I can also do a jsfiddle if needed, but maybe someone can see conflicts with new jquery version in my code ?

thanks a lot for your help,

Comment: Add jQuery Migrate (http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin)

Comment: As usual: define "doesn't work".

Comment: BTW, there's very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16397202/how-to-get-the-js-plugin-roundabout-working-with-jquery-v1-8-3-or-greater

Answer (score 0):

After loading jQuery, use: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js and this should help

Comment: thanks @kJamesy, so I use the 1.7.1 version and add the http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js ?

Comment: Use the latest version of jQuery and add this migrate after. And then use your plugin as normal

Comment: hum it doesn't work... I'm using wordpress, so I'm not sure if I'm doing it right in my function.php... do you wordpress ?

Comment: Yes I do. Are you sure there isn't any other version of jQuery elsewhere? Can I take a look at your page source. Paste it on: http://laravel.io/bin

Comment: I think I can see the problem. Could you please paste the page source as it appears when rendered.

Comment: Right click on the page and select 'View Source'

Comment: ok here it is, I've just deleted some meta description...
http://laravel.io/bin/dQbv

Comment: Could you join this: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/50551/jquery-help?tab=general